# how to convert sqlrebuilt index to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

I am trying to run rebuild index using C# from my database query, but I've encountered this problem? Any ideas?

Here is my rebuild index query in C#:

```
public static string rebuildIndex = "ALTER INDEX ALL @tablename REBUILD PARTITION = @partition_number WITH (ONLINE = ON)";
```

Here is the code from the respective function:

```
static void rebuildIndex(string query,string tablename, int parNumber)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tablename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partition_number", parNumber);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And here is the error msg.

```
*ERROR yourmessage Incorrect syntax near '@tablename'. [HouseKeep_VC.Program] [1]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '@tablename'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: You can't pass table name as well as partition number via bind variable.

Comment: Then how can i do it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Looks like it will accept a partition number, but obviously not a table name https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b899fca27c64e97cd58f15102f11e867

Comment: You need dynamic SQL to do this. Also you should not cache the connection object, create it when yu need it and dispose as soon as you're finished

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: c# is not in the game for your problem. When dealing with such kind of error, try to execute your query in SqlServer Management studio (or some similar tool) and fix the error there as a start

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL for the table name, it cannot be parameterized. Make sure to use `QUOTENAME` to quote the name correctly

- You should also create and dispose the connection, rather than caching it.
- You should specify parameter types (and lengths) explicitly.

```sql
static void rebuildIndex(string schemaName, string tablename, int parNumber)
{
    const string rebuildIndex = @"
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
  ALTER INDEX ALL ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + '
  REBUILD PARTITION = @partition_number
  WITH (ONLINE = ON);
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@partition_number int',
  @partition_number = @partition_number;
";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(YourConString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@schemaName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).value = schemaName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tablename", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).value = tablename;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@partition_number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parNumber;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```